# Robot framework keyword doesn't fail when exception occurs

Tags: exception, robotframework

In my case, I want to check something in the web UI until I got the expected result.
Here is the main step:

```
wait until keyword succeeds     15min    2min    login and check
```

In the keyword "login and check", I have:
`login to webui`   (there is no `run keyword and ignore error` used)
check and fail if no expected result

What confused me is: The keyword `login and check`  didn't fail when webdriver exception occured in `login to webui`, but continue the next step `check and fail if no expected result`, which failed also. And the next round didn't start at all.

Why? Isn't it supposed to fail and exit the first round after 2mins when the exception occured?
BTW: I am using robotframwork 3.1.2, and Selenium 3.141.0.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide a piece of the script you have used? It's impossible to [reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the current description.

Comment: Sorry, that was merely a mistake made by myself.   The KWs were put in teardown session instead of test case.